# A straightforward solution to a simple differential question doesn't make sense. What's wrong with it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is motivated by a physics problem: an object moving at velocity $v_0$ enters a $w$-meter thick medium which takes the object $T$ seconds to traverse. Assuming the resistance force is proportional to object's velocity squared, find object's velocity when it leaves the medium.

The equation is straightforward: $mv'=-k_1v^2$. Letting $\frac{k_1}{m}=k>0$, we have $v'=-kv^2$. Solving which, together with $v(0)=v_0$, produces $v(t)=\frac{v_0}{1+v_0kt}$. Now, letting $y'(t)=v(t)$, we get
$$
y'=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{t+\frac{1}{v_0k}},t>0.
$$
This results in
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(t+\frac{1}{v_0k}\right)+C
$$
without the absolute value sign under the logarithm, since everything is positive. $C$ can be found from the initial condition $y(0)=0$, giving $C=\frac{1}{k}\ln(v_0k)$. Hence
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(1+v_0kt\right).
$$
We know that it takes the object $T$ seconds to traverse $w$-thick medium, so
$$
w=\frac{1}{k}\ln(1+v_0kT),
$$
which, if we know values of $w,v_0,T$, we can solve numerically for $k$. This is where it gets strange. Putting $w=0.04,T=0.0001,v_0=200$ results in $k\approx-39.84$. A negative value! Why? When plugged into equation for $v(t)$, this leads to a physically nonsensical value for exit velocity: $v(T)\approx984$.

What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$200$ meters per second, for $0.0001$ seconds, means a travel distance of only $0.02$ meters. In order to travel the medium with thickness $0.04$, the speed will need to increase.

Answer (score 1):

Why is that velocity nonsensical? If we had no resistance and constant velocity, the object would travel $v_0T = .02$, but the object has width $.04$, so the average velocity must be twice as fast ($400$). Thus the object must accelerate (go faster) in the medium in order to get through so quickly. So the resistance is negative and the acceleration is positive.